# List Objects into Individual CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a list of dataframes which I wish to convert to multiple csv.

**Example:**

```
List_Df = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
for i in List_Df:
    i.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\"+i+".csv")
```

**Expected output:** Having 4 csv files with the names df1.csv,df2.csv ...

But I am facing two problems:

First problem:

```
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Second problem:

```
("C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\"+ **i** +".csv") <- **i** returns the object
    as it's suppose to but I wish for python to automatically take the
    object_name and use it with .csv
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am new to Python and SOF.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

List_Df = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
for i,e in enumerate(List_Df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(e)
    df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\"+"df"+str(i)+".csv")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just need to convert "i" to string as csv names cant start with int. Also solution provided by "Shintlor" works perfectly for anyone looking for a solution in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem you would have to e.g. name the dataframes first:

```
for j,df in enumerate(List_Df):
    df.name = 'df'+str(j)
    df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\%s.csv" %(df.name))
```

or even just take a string and add the index without naming the dataframes first:

```
for j,df in enumerate(List_Df):
    name = 'df'+str(j)
    df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\%s.csv" %(name))
```